# How to make this table structure responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm trying to get a resposive table with a % and not hard coded pixel values, but the column in which I want to place the image gets very small when I resize the window.

HTML:

```
<TABLE BORDER=1 style="width: 90%; margin: 5%;">
    <TR>
        <TD width="70%">
            <h4>ABOUT US</h4>
            <p spellcheck="false" style="padding: 15px;">content contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent 
            content contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent 
            content contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent
            </p>
            <p>content contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</p>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </TD>
        <TD width="30%" rowspan=2><img src="images/foto.jpeg"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <h4>MEET THE TEAM</h4>
            <p>content</p>
        </TD>
</TABLE>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qna3d/)

Is there any way to do this so that the table resize in such manner that the `column 2` becomes `row 3`? If I would have to do the same thing using divs I would by okay with that.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Are you trying to set rowspan and colspan? If so, what for? It's really hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Are you trying to do: <img src="images/foto.jpeg" height="100%" width="100%" />  ?

Comment: Actual I have divided my page in two column grid using table and on the right side I have to place only one image whereas on the left in two rows of the first column I have to write something. I thought it will do. And it actually did but, its no more responsive. I want a responsive alternative even without tables?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by responsive, the tables are not interactive, and load fairly quickly.

Comment: So how is it possible using divs without jquery i.e. when window resized then divs should come into rows one below another. I will remove the table

Comment: You mean you want to change the table completely when the window is resized? Tables scale without any issues.

Comment: Yeah i want to achieve the same. But this ain't work in my fiddle don't know why?

Comment: try closing your img tag, eg <img ... /> or <img></img>

Comment: Are you using tables to lay things out here?

Comment: I guess I have got the right direction or a thumb rule that tables don't gel properly with responsive design , atleast in 95% cases.

Comment: You can try using CSS to set width and height of individual cell(image) that does not scale well, also I think there is a minimum-size properties in CSS, but I do not remember them

Comment: I modified your fiddle, I think that's what you wanted? By setting minimum-width, your image does not go screwy when your text no longer fits, just decide the minimum, and it should scale fine.

Comment: Hi @pKs, please _always_ post your code in your question rather than just using jsFiddle and some random highlighting.

Comment: @Ben Sure I will keep this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a simple rule when it comes to responsive web design (or any web design in general)...

#### Never

### Ever

## Ever

... Use tables to define the layout of a page. Tables are designed to present tabular data  not to define the layout of a page. Use `div` elements instead

A useful link to bear in mind is http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/.

Answer (score 6):

Tables shouldn't be used for layout (as @davblayn pointed out), but if you want/need to use them:

HTML:

```
<TABLE BORDER=1 style="width: 90%; margin: 5%;">
    <TR>
        <TD id='firstItem' width="70%">
            <h4>ABOUT US</h4>
            <p spellcheck="false" style="padding: 15px;">content contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent 
            content contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent 
            content contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent
            </p>
            <p>content contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent</p>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </TD>
        <TD width="30%" id='responsiveItem' rowspan=2><img src="images/foto.jpeg"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <h4>MEET THE TEAM</h4>
            <p>content</p>
        </TD>
</TABLE>
```

CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
    td{
        width:100%;
    }
    #firstItem{
        display:block;
    }
    #responsiveItem{
        float:left;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTksA/)

Play with resizing the JSFiddle window, the `column` with the image drops down to become a `row` when there isn't enough room.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I realise the questioner has posted all code in a jsFiddle but if you could _always_ post your code in your answer or question it would be much appreciated. The goal is to help people easily in the future not solely the original poster. For this reason an explanation of what's happening and why is also always appreciated. Many thanks and good luck!

Comment: -1 because tables shouldn't be used for design / layout purposes

Comment: @NicWortel, I understand that. But the asker was using tables, and since another user created a "best practice" answer, I created an answer to solve the O.P's current implementation (which was using tables.) See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145909/the-best-practice-answer-etiquette for more details.

Comment: @NicWortel, I did add a warning at the top of my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use tables for layout. You can't easily do what you want with CSS anyway, since you'd have to override the display property for multiple elements.

Comment: +1 on this answer. Tables for layout are a bad idea in most cases, and are a terrible idea for layout in a responsive design. So the best way to solve this problem is to avoid it and use better layout practices.

Comment: Tables for layouts are still a must for HTML based emails, there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

If by "responsive" you mean does not go screwy when text does not fit, and maintains image size (images do not scale nicely), then you can use this:

```
    <table border="1" width="800px" height="250" style="min-width:800px; width: 90%; margin: 5%;">
      <tr> 
        <td>
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
        </td>
        <td style="height: 250px; width: 250px;" rowspan="2">CONTENT</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Basically, you need to set minimum space to accomodate the content, then you can scale outwards as much as you want.

While yes, tables are generally frowned upon, it is another form of "WHY WOULD YOU WANT TO DO THAT" and since the question particularly asks for tables, there is no need to completely change the question to satisfy your pet peeve.

Tables work fine for websites, the main issue with them is that they take a while to set up, and once they are set up, they stay that way forever, and changing them is impossible without total re-tabling.

This does not appear to the main issue here.